# How do I by pass startup code in access

Tags: ms-access

I am struggling to by pass my startup code in MS Access using the SHIFT + ENTER keys. How else can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the SHIFT key while opening your database.

-> Depending on the macro security settings for your database, you might see one or more security messages on startup. You must hold down the SHIFT key until you close the security messages, or the startup options will not be bypassed.